# Replicate Azure EasyTable functionality

Tags: sql, azure

Azure recently announced that they are discontinuing the EasyTable and EasyAPI aspects of App Services. I've extensively used both of these, and want to continue to do so.

[this article](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2019/07/25/Removing-Easy-Tables-and-Easy-APIs-from-Azure-App-Services.html) explains that all the existing functionality is still there, you just manually have to do it yourself. Now I'm relatively comfortable with creating basic SQL tables myself, but azure easy tables have some special properties that I don't know how to create.

When you creat an Azure Easy Table, it creates an id column which has auto-created values that look like `dc405ef6-6c40-465d-ba8a-00e1ad86d5e4` - I know how to make an auto-incrementing id column but not one like that. It also has columns for createdAt and updatedAt, of type datetimeoffset, which get automatically filled in.

What's the `CREATE TABLE` commands to replicate this?

Also, not sure if there's something special I have to do to make my odata queries not have `deleted` rows show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the CREATE TABLE commands to replicate this?

You can set the default value of the column to be [`NEWID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function and it will insert a GUID as value for that column.

Comment: oh okay, so this code would be how to do it? `CREATE TABLE cust  
(  
 CustomerID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL  
   DEFAULT newid(),`

Comment: Do you have any advice on the createdAt and updatedAt columns?

Comment: Assuming they're `DateTime` data type, you can use `GETDATE()` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

Comment: Well I could do that in each individual query, yes, but I think the tables as they are on Azure do it automatically. If I insert a row, the `createdAt` automatically updates to the current date, and if I update a row, `updatedAt` gets updated automatically.

Comment: I found this https://gist.github.com/bdcravens/4340724 , not sure if that's the full functionality but it looks good...